# How to Store Json Object as a string in a Single Column in java

Tags: arrays, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

How to save/retrieve below Json Object into database like all rule should contain array as string:

```
[{"ID":1,
 "parentId":1,
 "level":1,
  "rule":"abc",
 "fieldName":"cds",
 "allrule":[
  {}
   ]
   },
  {"ID":2,
  "parentId":2,
  "level":2,
  "rule":"abcas",
  "fieldName":"cdgf",
  "allrule":[{"firstname":"rohit","min":5,"max":10}
  ]
  }
  ]
```

Here values inside "all rule" object can be dynamic like there could be any no of key value pair at run time.
I hope its not confusing problem statement
I tried @OneToMany logic and stored Json object data in separate table Code snippet:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Allrule")
public class ListofRules {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int allruleId;
    private String key1;
    private String value1;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Rule rule;
//getters,setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "Rule")
public class Rule {

    @Id
    private int ID;
    private int parentId;
    private int level;
    private String rule;
    private String fieldName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="rule_id")
    private List<ListofRules> listofrules;

    //getter,setter
 }
```

But I need to save and retrive Json data as below Output like below:
 As per my logic I am getting json response like:

```
[
 {"ID":1,
 "parentId":1,
 "level":1,
 "rule":"abc",
"fieldName":"cds",
 allrule":[{}]
 },
 {"ID":2,
 "parentId":2,
 "level":2,
 "rule":"abcas",
 "fieldName":"cdgf",
 "allrule":[{"Key1":"rohit","value1":5},{"Key1":"dinesh","value1":19}]
 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson Object mapper for converting Object to string and visa-Versa,

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: I have referred the link given above, the solution given is to store the json object having known fields, but in my problem statement "allrule" json array has unknown field which will be decided at run time.

Comment: Doesn't matter you can declare it as POJO and cast it later